# Stadlaone-full set up for wildfly

Tags: jms, wildfly-8, hornetq, wildfly-10

i'm tryin to run an app that runs on jboss EAP , on jboss Wildfly , but i'm having problems with the standalone-full.xml because some services like hornetq aren't available on Wildfly
is there a possible way to migrate from eap to wildfly?

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your app.
Wildfly 10 ships with ActiveMq rather than HornetQ.

If your app uses standard JMS then you can configure the WF10 standalone-full to have the same JMS endpoints as your old deployment. If however your app is using the HornetQ specific client you will have to do some more work. ActiveMQ artemis integrates HornetQ protocols but it probably won't work without some trial and error in the configuration.

I would suggest starting with standalone-full.xml from Wildfly 10 and compare it with your JBoss EAP configuration. There should be an analog for each service you need. Once that is set try running your app and see what happens.

Comment: thk u very much that was very helpfull